# Networkx edge not adding attributes correctly

Tags: python, networkx, edges, graphml

I've pulled up some code I used to play with in 1.6.1 of networkx. On 1.8.1 it doesn't work when writing to `gml` or `graphml`.

The problem boils down to being unable to write edge attributes inside the data dict like so:

```
BasicGraph = nx.read_graphml("KeggCompleteEng.graphml")

for e,v in BasicGraph.edges_iter():
    BasicGraph[e][v]['test'] = 'test'

nx.write_graphml(BasicGraph, "edgeTester.graphml")
```

Causes the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

When I use: `for e,v,data in BasicGraph.edges_iter(data=True):` the data prints out like so:

```
{'root_index': -3233, 'label': u'unspecified'}
test
```

AKA the new attribute is outside the dictionary.

The documentation says I should be able to do it like above. However, I imagine I've made a silly mistake and would appreciate being put back on the right path!

EDIT:

So I ran the program with a graph generated inside the program:  `BasicGraph = nx.complete_graph(100)` and it ran fine.

I then ran it with an example graphml file from the primer: `BasicGraph = nx.read_graphml("graphmltest.graphml")` and that too worked. (I even imported into and out of Cytoscape to check that wasn't the issue)

So obviously it's the file I'm using. [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bohcohpz8kxbk7t/KeggCompleteEng.graphml) a link to it, can anyone see what's wrong with it?

Comment: can you modify your code to not require loading that file?

Comment: Tried it with `nx.complete_graph()` and another graphml file, they both worked fine. See updates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your graph is has parallel edges so NetworkX is loading it as a MultiGraph object:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.read_graphml('KeggCompleteEng.graphml')

In [3]: type(G)
Out[3]: networkx.classes.multigraph.MultiGraph

In [4]: G.number_of_edges()
Out[4]: 7123

In [5]: H = nx.Graph(G) # convert to graph, remove parallel edges

In [6]: H.number_of_edges()
Out[6]: 6160
```

Because of that the internal structure of the graph object storage for an edge is G[node][node][key][attribute]=value (note the extra key dictionary level for multigraphs).

You are explicitly modifying the structure by

```
for e,v in BasicGraph.edges_iter():
    BasicGraph[e][v]['test'] = 'test'
```

which breaks it.

It is allowed to modify the data structure that way but it is safer to use the NetworkX API

```
In [7]: G = nx.MultiGraph()

In [8]: G.add_edge(1,2,key='one')

In [9]: G.add_edge(1,2,key='two')

In [10]: G.edges(keys=True)
Out[10]: [(1, 2, 'two'), (1, 2, 'one')]

In [11]: G.add_edge(1,2,key='one',color='red')

In [12]: G.add_edge(1,2,key='two',color='blue')

In [13]: G.edges(keys=True,data=True)
Out[13]: [(1, 2, 'two', {'color': 'blue'}), (1, 2, 'one', {'color': 'red'})]
```